# javascript indexOf with millions of matches

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, indexof

I'm trying to extract a few lines representing some XML elements from a file.
The user provides a file using a simple `<input type="file">` tag, and than this file is read as text with `FileReader`, and given as the parameter to this function:

```
var relevantDelimiters = [{"begin":"<header>","end":"</header>"}
,{"begin":" <someElement>","end":"</someElement>"}];

function dealWithString(invalidXML) {
  var validXML = "";
  for (var i=0; i<relevantDelimiters.length; i++) {
    delimiter = relevantDelimiters[i];
    while (invalidXML.indexOf(delimiter.begin) != -1) {
      //while there are relevant elements of this kind left: 
      startPos = invalidXML.indexOf(delimiter.begin);
      endPos = invalidXML.indexOf(delimiter.end); 
      //append to end result:
      validXML+=invalidXML.substring(startPos,endPos+delimiter.end.length)+"\n";
      //take this item out of the input to process next item
      invalidXML = invalidXML.replace(invalidXML.substring(startPos,endPos+delimiter.end.length),"");
    }
  }
  //return fixed data
  return validXML;
}
```

This approach seems to work just fine with a small amount of matches in the input text file, but given a file of 1.5MB, script is stuck (Running with Google Chrome, making it's tab non-responsive). This file contains about a million "relevant elements", meaning matches from `relevantDelimiters`.

How can I optimize this?

Comment: You can use a [WebWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/basic_usage) so that the browser's UI can keep running while you are searching.

Comment: @JuanMendes: That sounds like an *answer* to me.

Comment: Pretty heavy string manipulation here, and while there are ways to improve performance I wonder if you couldn't get more bang for your buck by passing it through an XSL template to remove the unwanted XML nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of repeatedly "taking the item out of the input" by calling `replace` on it, you should use the second argument to [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf): `fromIndex`. That way, it'll search the next occurence after the given index, and you can loop through the very large input without needing to touch it.

```
function dealWithString(invalidXML) {
  var validXML = "";
  for (var i=0; i<relevantDelimiters.length; i++) {
    var delimiter = relevantDelimiters[i],
        pos = 0,
        startPos;
    while ((startPos = invalidXML.indexOf(delimiter.begin, pos)) != -1) {
      //while there are relevant elements of this kind left:
      var endPos = invalidXML.indexOf(delimiter.end, startPos);
      // assert(endPos != -1) - otherwise this could go horribly wrong
      pos = endPos+delimiter.end.length;
      //append to end result:
      validXML += invalidXML.slice(startPos, pos) + "\n";
    }
  }
  return validXML;
}
```

Comment: That would definitely improve the speed. May still need [Juan's idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29086481/javascript-indexof-with-millions-of-matches#comment46405953_29086481) *as well*, esp. if the warning is based on iterations rather than actual time as in at least some versions of IE, but definitely would improve speed.

Answer (score 0):

Where's the time being spent? I assume you could break up this big synchronous action into a couple of async hopes. (Every couple of while-iterations, you could store your index and set-timeout before resuming. This way you don't lock the UI thread.

Comment: Doing so is probably a mechanism of last resort, though -- it **dramatically** slows things down when the browser takes 4-10ms to call you back. Web worker (where available) is a much better idea.

Comment: Web workers are only a "better idea" if the user doesn't care about IE 8 or 9.

Comment: Nobody cares about IE 8/9 :)

Comment: If only that were true... ;)

Comment: @brianvaughn: I said *where available*. (And yeah: If only no one cared about IE8 [no one **does** care about IE9].)

Comment: Okay. I wasn't trying to be pedantic or anything. Just pointing out that web workers *aren't an option* for many people- especially those writing E&E software.